# Easy way to update Excel data to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I have a database with some tables "Products, Cores, Clients, ProdCliPrice, etc"

I am developing a software and one of it's functions is to update (or insert) the data in an Excel file to my database.

The Excel file contain a ProductID, a Core Name and a Product Price.

I wrote a code that stores all Core Names and Ids to a array, and then, line by line insert (or update if already exists) the product to the database. Since I have more than 100k rows, it is taking too long.

Could you help me with a better way to insert or update these data?

Comment: If you have access to SQL Server Management Studio, you can use the Import/Export wizard.

Comment: I have but others users won't, there's anyway to "call" the wizard using C#?

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you have installed?

Comment: https://www.excel-sql-server.com/excel-import-to-sql-server-using-linked-servers.htm

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175915.aspx

Comment: I have SQL Server 2014 Express and Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You coud either use `BULK INSERT` directly in SQL Server Management Studio like this:

```
BULK INSERT [DataBase].[dbo].YourTable
FROM 'filepath'
WITH
(
    Firstrow = 1,
    Fieldterminator=';',
    Rowterminator='\n',
    Codepage = 'ACP'
)
```

For Excel-Files (.xls) you can use this:

```
SELECT * INTO YourTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=YourFilePath', [ExcelSheet$])
```

You may have to replace the `8.0` with your current office version (`8.0` is for Office 2000, `14.0` is for Office 2010, for example).

There's also [SqlBulkCopy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#.

If you don't want to import all columns, I suggest you write a small program, load the file into a `DataTable`, drop all the columns you don't need and then use `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: will that work for Excel?  This looks a .csv import.

Comment: This really looks like a .csv import; My Excel file have headers and if it's possible I don't want to import all columns

Comment: @G.Knoxx I updated the answer with an import for excel files. But it sounds like you're better off writing a small program in `C#`.